# Select newest version from table (MS SQL Server, SQLite)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Let's say, I have the following table:

```
ID | UID | Version | Content
---+-----+---------+-----------------------------
 1 |   1 |       1 | Something
 2 |   1 |       2 | Something (changed)
 3 |   2 |       1 | Alice has a cat
 4 |   2 |       2 | Alice has a cat and a dog
 5 |   2 |       3 | Alice has a cat and a canary
```

I need to create query, which will return all objects, but only with newest version, so in this case:

```
ID | UID | Version | Content
---+-----+---------+-----------------------------
 2 |   1 |       2 | Something (changed)
 5 |   2 |       3 | Alice has a cat and a canary
```

Since SQL dialects differ, I'll be running this query on MS Sql Server 2008 and SQLite 3.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` query:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.uid = t1.uid
                    and t2.version > t1.version)
```

`JOIN` query:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
    join (select uid, max(version) as version from tablename group by uid) t2
    on t2.uid = t1.uid and t2.version = t1.version
```

Correlated sub-query:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where t1.version = (select max(version) from tablename t2
                    where t2.uid = t1.uid)
```

`IN` sub-query:

```
select *
from tablename
where (uid, version) IN (select uid, max(version) from tablename
                         group by uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to solve this problem.  But each approach follows the same principle.

A section of your query will identify the lastest version for each UID.  This will then be used to filter the recordset.

In the example below I've found the current version of each UID using a sub query, which I've then used to filter the main recordset.

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403394/find-current-version)

```
/* This table gives us some sample records
 * to experiment with.
 */
DECLARE @Example TABLE
    (
        ID            INT                PRIMARY KEY,
        [UID]        INT                NOT NULL,
        [Version]    INT                NOT NULL,
        Content        VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
    )
;

/* Populate the sample data.
 */
INSERT INTO @Example
    (
        ID,
        [UID],
        [Version],
        Content
    )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'Something'),
    (2, 1, 2, 'Something (changed)'),
    (3, 2, 1, 'Alice has a cat'),
    (4, 2, 2, 'Alice has a cat and a dog'),
    (5, 2, 3, 'Alice has a cat and a canary')
;

/* Return the most recent version of each UID.
 * This is done by using a sub query to calcualte the max of each UIDs version.
 */
SELECT
    e.*
FROM
    @Example AS e
        INNER JOIN
            (    
                /* This sub query finds the max version of
                 * each UID.
                 */
                SELECT
                    [UID],
                    MAX([Version]) AS Current_Version
                FROM
                    @Example    
                GROUP BY
                    [UID]
            ) AS mv
        ON    mv.[UID]            = e.[UID]
        AND    mv.Current_Version    = e.[Version]
;
```